# Javascript for offline html documentation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create documentation for use offline (included on a microSD card). I can't assume that the user will have Internet access, nor do I want to assume they will have any installed applications besides a web browser. Therefore, I want to utilize the web browser to dynamically read files. For example, the page might look like this:

---

### Select chapter: <drop-down-list>

Once they select the chapter from a drop-down list, it will simply display under the "Select chapter" part.

Each chapter is a separate .html file. I thought of going old-school with frames, but even then I don't know how I would load the frame based on the drop down item selected. Then I thought I would consider Ajax to not be so 1996, but it seemed like the method for AJAX is "GET" which requires a real webserver.

I know this is very vague, but if somebody has the skills to just whip out a sample how to do this any way possible, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<a href="..." target="framename"> selected chapter </a>`.

To be more specific, Because you are using a select box, you should implement an `onchange` method which does something like

`document.getElementById('your target frame ID').src="your source html path";`.

Please note : Though your question is reasonable and you have understanding of other options available to you, due to exaggerated writing you would get downvotes. You better edit your question just to the point.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation and the posting tip!

Answer (score 0):

Only some browsers will support reading local files using XHR by default (Firefox does, Chrome needs extra flags).
IMHO you should use simple hypertext/HTML instead.
You could have it all in one page but hide/show what you want on chapter selection. Or simply make a huge html with a table of contents on top and use anchors (classic FAQ, help...).